# Making another image change while hovering over another

Tags: html, css, hover

*Hello
I am making a project, where I have a map and imagebuttons.*

*Check the image*  [image]

*The maps are stacked on top of eachother and I can get one with Z-Index when I hard code it.
But I want the Z-Index to go up when I hover over the corresponding imagebutton.
So when I hover over "Workdesks [53]" the map is not "Fixed desks" image but the "Workdesks" image.
I know this possible with just CSS and Z-Index
But I just dont know how?
Can you help me?*

*HTML;*

```
    <div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-6">

            <img src="../IMAGE/Plattegronden/Deck A/A Deck Default.png" width="65%" class="hoverimage1">

            <img src="../IMAGE/Plattegronden/Deck A/Workdesks Deck A.png" width="65%" class="hoverimage2">

            <img src="../IMAGE/Plattegronden/Deck A/Fixed desks Deck A.png" width="65%" class="hoverimage3">

        </div>

        <div class="col-4">

        </div>

        <div class="col-2">

            <br />

            <img src="../IMAGE/Buttons/Workdesks [53].png" width="75%">
            <br />
            <br />

            <img src="../IMAGE/Buttons/Fixed desks [4].png" width="75%">
            <br />
            <br />

            <img src="../IMAGE/Buttons/Huddle [1].png" width="75%">
            <br />
            <br />

            <img src="../IMAGE/Buttons/Conference room Large [2].png" width="75%">
            <br />
            <br />

            <img src="../IMAGE/Buttons/Conference room Small [1].png" width="75%">
            <br />
            <br />

            <img src="../IMAGE/Buttons/Phoneboot [2].png" width="75%">
            <br />
            <br />

            <img src="../IMAGE/Buttons/Private office [1].png" width="75%">
            <br />
            <br />

            <img src="../IMAGE/Buttons/Medical room [1].png" width="75%">
            <br />
            <br />

            <img src="../IMAGE/Buttons/Luggage room [1].png" width="75%">

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

*CSS;*

```
.hoverimage1 {
 margin-top: 30px;
 position: absolute;
 }

.hoverimage2 {
 margin-top: 30px;
 position: absolute;
 }

.hoverimage3 {
 margin-top: 30px;
 position: absolute;
 }
```

Comment: Try with the ```hover``` property in CSS. For example: ```img:hover{ background-color:black; }```. In your case you can set the z-index as you like.

Comment: You have a good point but that only works when I hover over the image itself not the corresponding imagebutton on the right

Comment: This forum may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11371550/change-hover-css-properties-with-javascript

Comment: I will check it out but is this also possible with just CSS? I never worked with JavaScript

Comment: Okay that's too bad than i think it is time for me to learn some JavaScript

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502633/how-to-affect-other-elements-when-one-element-is-hovered try this! But I think that you need to learn Javascript if you want to create a simple website.

Comment: Thanks Marco I know I still need to learn JavaScript but this is a very small school project and I am really new to this stuff so where i can just use HTML and CSS I will use only that ;)

Comment: You can do it with CSS alone, but you would need to change your markup quite a bit In CSS you can select a sibling, there for, if your images were siblings of your menu, you could affect them while hovering the menu.