# How can I change CSS with JavaScript for transitions?

Tags: javascript, css

Trying:

```
document.querySelector(".element:hover").style["background"] = "red";
```

The code didn't work for me because of the ":hover".
In order to change the background-color of the element when it has hovered, what can I do?

Comment: Why don't you use pure CSS?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change :hover CSS properties with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11371550/change-hover-css-properties-with-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:hover` is not something JS can affect. Use CSS instead:

```css
.element:hover {
  background: red;
}
```

Note that [event listeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) can also do this, but they would not be as elegant as CSS:

```js
div.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
  div.classList.add('active');
});

div.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
  div.classList.remove('active');
});
```

Try it:

```js
const checkbox = document.querySelector('input');
const div = document.querySelector('div');

div.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
  if (!checkbox.checked) {
    div.classList.add('active');
  }
});
div.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
  if (!checkbox.checked) {
    div.classList.remove('active');
  }
});
```

```css
label:has(:checked) + div:hover,
.active {
  background: red;
}

div {
  margin: 30px 0;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<label>Use CSS: <input type="checkbox" checked></label>

<div>Hover me!</div>
```

Comment: You edited your answer after seeing my answer to add mouseover event :)

Comment: @Rohit I did not :) We edited at the same time but I was slower by a bit.

Comment: No issues. Good answer anyways 

Answer (score 1):

You can use a CSS variable to control the background on hover, which can also be set in JavaScript.

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', e => {
  document.querySelector('.element').style.setProperty('--background', 'red');
});
```

```css
.element:hover {
  --background: dodgerblue;
  background: var(--background);
}
```

```html
<div class="element">
Hover over here
</div>
<button>Change hover color</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to @inSync 's approach.
In case , you need a pure JS solution , you could use the `mouseover` event as below :

```js
const myDiv = document.querySelector(".mydiv");

myDiv.addEventListener("mouseover", (event) => {
  event.target.style.background = "Red";
});
```

```html
<div class="mydiv">
  Hover over me !
</div>
```

Mouseover event : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseover_event