# javascript beginner: add a dynamic style in javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create a <style> tag with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/524696/how-to-create-a-style-tag-with-javascript)

I write a dynamic form using java-script. I want to add the style in java-script itself. I write some code to add a style. But it is not working.This is the code am write in my project.

```
var sheet = document.createElement('style');
sheet.type="text/css";
sheet.innerHTML = "body{color:red;}";
document.body.appendChild(sheet);
```

Anyone help me please.

Comment: `style` elements have to be in the `head`.

Comment: +1 on @FelixKling  Append that puppy to the head.

Comment: Mmmh, it actually works in Chrome as well... maybe the issue is indeed somewhere else, but afaik, `style` element are only valid inside `head`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is fine.But i think that you are not calling it on right time, so call it when your body tag is loaded

```
 window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){
    var sheet = document.createElement('style'); 
    sheet.type="text/css"; 
    sheet.innerHTML = "body{color:red;}"; 
    document.body.appendChild(sheet);
    }, false);
```

Comment: There isn't a need to create a file for this.  You can do the same with creating a `<style>` element.  It might be a difficult thing to do if this is in a CMS and he doesn't have FTP access.

Comment: Friend. I got a error `document.head[0]`.  I want to write the whole style in java-script itself. I wont go to use css file. So explain it clearly.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just add the style through a class?

```
.blue {
   background-color: blue;   
}​

document.body.className = 'blue';​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kf8Nd/

If you really need a whole stylesheet, just add it to your header instead.

```
var sheet = document.createElement('style');
sheet.type="text/css";
sheet.innerHTML = "body{color:red;}";
document.head.appendChild(sheet); // head, not body
```

Comment: +1 as downvote is entirely undeserved

Comment: Friend. I want to write the whole style in java-script itself. I wont go to use css file. So explain it clearly.

Comment: @yuva edited for clarity, thought that part was self-explanatory.

Comment: it will not work as style in body tag  was not the error

Answer (score 1):

[HERE](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/dynamic-style-css-javascript/) you can have some more resource to increase your knowledge. And I'm sure an example will be very useful! There are some SO questions that would help you too like [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/change-an-elements-css-class-with-javascript/196038). *--Credits [Peter Boughton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9360/peter-boughton)*

This was tested in IE, FF and Opera:

```
var css = 'h1 { background: red; }',
    head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
    style = document.createElement('style');

style.type = 'text/css';
if(style.styleSheet){
    style.styleSheet.cssText = css;
}else{
    style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
}
head.appendChild(style);
```

To add a class to an element:

```
document.getElementById("MyElement").className += " MyClass";
```

To remove a class from an element:

```
document.getElementById("MyElement").className = 
   document.getElementById("MyElement").className.replace
      ( /(?:^|\s)MyClass(?!\S)/ , '' )
/* code wrapped for readability - above is all one statement */
```

To do that in an onclick event:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeClass()
    {
        // code examples from above
    }
</script>
...
<button onclick="changeClass()">My Button</button>
```

Better yet, use a framework (in this example jQuery) which allows you to do the following:

```
$j('#MyElement').addClass('MyClass');

$j('#MyElement').removeClass('MyClass');

$j('#MyElement').toggleClass('MyClass');
```

And also:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeClass()
    {
        // code examples from above
    }

    $j(':button:contains(My Button)').click(changeClass);
</script>
...
<button>My Button</button>
```

This is separating HTML markup from your JS interaction logic, which is something that - especially on large/complex applications - can make maintenance significantly easier.

Answer (score 0):

Add the style to the head element not the body

```
var sheet = document.createElement('style');
sheet.type="text/css";
sheet.innerHTML = "body{color:red;}";
document.head.appendChild(sheet);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var style = document.createElement('style');
style.type = 'text/css';
style.innerHTML = 'body{color:red;}';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);
```