# Unexpected call to method or property access. in JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code which is giving error in IE8

```
$(function(){
 $.ajax({url:"http://localhost/css/register.txt",  
         cache : false,
         success:function(ris){$("<style></style>").appendTo("head").html(ris);//culprit statement
          },
         error:function(){}
                                    });
});
```

Comment: Try replacing `.html(ris)` with `.text(ris)`. ...or try `$("<style>" + ris + "</style>")`

Comment: $("<style>" + ris + "</style>") worked but can you tell me why my code not worked

Comment: All I know is that there are browser compatibility issues when setting the content of a `<style>` element. Apparently jQuery doesn't fix this with its `.html()` method.

Comment: Did that technique work in the other browsers as well? I'd hate to leave a solution if it breaks in some other browser.

Comment: yes it is working in all browsers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that jQuery doesn't resolve the browser compatibility issues regarding setting the content of a `<style>` element via `innerHTML`.

I believe this will work instead...

```
$("<style>" + ris + "</style>")
```

Answer (score 3):

Internet Explorer does not allow setting of `innerHTML` on `<style>` elements. See [How to create a <style> tag with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/524696/1048572)

Comment: But `am not i am`'s solution is working fine.Did you see any errors in his solution

Comment: Not sure how jQuery handles such html snippets, yet in the linked question Chrome did not like creation of full <style> elements via innerHTML. At least, you should test.

Comment: Then there is no reason not to use it :-)