# Remove print button from hard copy

Tags: javascript, button, printing, hide, show-hide

With reference to [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_print.asp) and [this](http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/newtech2.shtml), I printing a report using javascript as

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function printpage()
{
var data = 'Sample Report<br />Sample Report<br />Sample Report<br />';
    var data = data+'<br/><button onclick="window.print()">Print the Report</button>';       
    myWindow=window.open('','','width=800,height=600');
    myWindow.innerWidth = screen.width;
    myWindow.innerHeight = screen.height;
    myWindow.screenX = 0;
    myWindow.screenY = 0;
    myWindow.document.write(data);
    myWindow.focus();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="button" value="Print Preview" onclick="printpage()" />

</body>
</html>
```

But after printing, the print button still remains at the hard copy. So how to hide the print button in hard copy when printing by using the above function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Give your button a class, e.g. `class="noprint"`. Then Add a stylesheet for print media to your CSS:

```
@media print {
  /* style sheet for print goes here */
  .noprint {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
}
```

Details: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html

Comment: When you add the necessary style sheets to the new window it should work, yes.

Comment: But not working. See the [sample here](http://jsfiddle.net/4d3jj/) @Gerald Schneider

Comment: @PradeepShankar you have placed the css in the parent window, it has no effect in the newly opened window. I found [this topic about adding css via javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/524696/how-to-create-a-style-tag-with-javascript), but I could't get it working yet. I'll take a deeper look at it when I'm done working. It should be something like this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GeraldS/aVeTV/1/

Comment: Please see the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17759945/print-button-in-hard-copy/17761020?noredirect=1#17761020

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this with the following css after assigning id to print button.

```
<style type="text/css">
@media print {
    #myPrntbtn {
        display :  none;
    }
}
</style>
```

And my button as follows.

```
<input id ="myPrntbtn" type="button" value="Print" onclick="window.print();" >
```

Also, you can run javascript function with the following actions...

1. Hide the button
2. Print the page using window.print();
3. Again Show back the button

Piece of code...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function printMyPage() {
        //Get the print button
        var printButton = document.getElementById("myPrntbtn");
        //Hide the print button 
        printButton.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        //Print the page content
        window.print()
        //Show back the print button on web page 
        printButton.style.visibility = 'visible';
    }
</script>
```

Reference [Hide Print button while printing a web page](http://www.gitarani.com/classified.htm?classifiedId=3752)