# How to I keep the "Print" and the URL from printing?

Tags: php, printing

I have a form that I set up for staff to fill out when ordering spray paint for our company. This form is submitted to a PHP page which shows the results of the order form and allows the user to print however. It also prints the print button as well as the URL to the page. How can I make it print without these two things? This is the code I am using inside the style tag...

```
@media print {
    .hide-on-print { display:none; }
}
```

And this is my print button...

```
echo '<br /><br /><a href="javascript:window.print()">Print</a>';
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can't hide the URL or any other header or footer text. These are settings controlled by the browser and are not accessible via any API. Ultimately it is up to the user to decide whether they are printed or not.

You can hide the print button by using `display:none` for that element in the print CSS for that page.

Comment: So how can I make a form to print out that does not contain the URL?

Comment: You can't. It's out of your control.

Comment: Not every form in the world prints the URL, so there must be a way.

Comment: Like I said, it is up to the user who controls their printer settings. If they don't disable that feature it will print by default (unless it is also off by default on the printer).

Comment: @ABBryan Don't they usually just open a separate chromeless window with the form data for printing?

Comment: The display: None works for the print button, but the URL is still troubling me...

Answer (score 0):

Recently I have seen here [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17759945/print-button-in-hard-copy/). **If you want to get rid of the URL address**, you can create a new window, copy the printable content there and print the new window, then close it. Then the original address will be replaced by the `about:blank`.

```js
function printpage() {
    var styles = document.getElementsByTagName('style');
    var style = '';
    for (var i=0; i<styles.length; i++) {
        style += styles[i].innerHTML;
    }
    var data = document.getElementById('print_content').innerHTML;
    data += '<br/><button onclick="window.print()" class="noprint">Print the Report</button>';
    data += '<br/><button onclick="window.close()" class="noprint">Close Preview</button>';
    data += '<style type="text/css" media="print"> .noprint {visibility: hidden;}</style><style type="text/css">'+ style +' </style>';
    myWindow = window.open('', '', 'width=800,height=600');
    myWindow.innerWidth = screen.width;
    myWindow.innerHeight = screen.height;
    myWindow.screenX = 0;
    myWindow.screenY = 0;
    myWindow.document.body.innerHTML = data;
    myWindow.focus();
}
```

[jsfiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/4d3jj/7/) + [result page](http://jsfiddle.net/4d3jj/7/show/) (works with IE7+)