# Insert css in external style sheet using jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I want to insert a style in external style sheet. Can anyone help me to do this?

The below code is not useful for me because it insert css as inline

```
$("#id").css('border','2px solid red')
```

Comment: You want to add these lines in altogether diffrent file?

Comment: I want to add the css using jquery in external css file

Comment: It's not very clear what exactly you're trying to achieve and *why* you want to do this. Please add more details, so that somebody can help you with an appropriate solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're saying is: using your example code it inserts as inline styles rather than creating its own external style sheet with the style that is then applied to your DOM.

If so [read this](http://www.w3.org/Submission/1996/1/WD-jsss-960822). It's from 1996 (woo!) but shows how to create `<style>` elements using javascript (so your CSS will live in the HTML `<head>` and not be inline. In terms of using Javascript to create external stylesheets? No idea, hopefully someone else can help.

Edit: found this on SO: [How to create a <style> tag with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/524696/how-to-create-a-style-tag-with-javascript) so no need to rely on something from '96.