# Is it possible to set background image for the chrome tabs in the top panel?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am looking into a way how to set custom backgrounds for all the open tabs. Is it possible?

One color would be a start, but in the end, I want to be able to set the whole background of the tab itself.

Thanks for any insight!

EDIT: I want to edit style of the little tab rectangles on the top, not of the pages themselves. Only the topmost panel that contains all the open tabs, I mean those.

Comment: Only [themes](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/themes) can do it in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can use a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) to [inject a CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50416555/dynamically-update-css-content-using-javascript/50416800#50416800) file into the pages you load. Extensions like [stylish](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish-custom-themes-for/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe?hl=en) do this already, so you may want to consider writing code for those plugins rather than creating your own.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I am not sure if you understood correctly. I don't want to change the background of a page, I want to change the background of the tab on the top where you see all your open tabs, I want to modify only this little rectangle. Any way to do that?

Comment: Only themes can do it in Chrome