# Can you hide <style class= in output html?

Tags: css, wordpress, styles, hide, output

Is it possible to hide `<style type="text/css" title="dynamic-css" class="options-output"></style>` in output html?
The Wordpress theme uses variable css a plants it in the header of every page.

For the sake of tidyness, is it possible to hide this output whilst still calling the styling within?

Comment: Do you mean that when you right click in web browser and select "Display source code" you don't want to see it?? Or you want to discard this style, so that the page does not use it?

Comment: The former.  I wish to hide this from the output html when you view source code.

Comment: Why would you want to hide it? This looks like a variant “How do I hide my HTML source?” (The answer is “by never publishing your page”.)

Answer (score 0):

You can delete what you don't want to see from template source code. Later dynamically create the style using javascript. The topic is widely covered. See for example this question: [How to create a <style> tag with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/524696/how-to-create-a-style-tag-with-javascript)

Comment: How is this relevant to the question? The op wants to hide the tags that already exist....

Comment: Correct Patsy Issa.  The tags are already there, I just want them hidden from the source code.

Comment: Ok.. can't you then delete this tag from Wordpress template and later add it dynamically with javascript (as posted in the answer) ?

Comment: When you say add it dynamically with javascript, are you suggesting calling a sepereate javascript file which contains the dynamic css?

Comment: You can do this in many ways. If you have your styles in separate stylesheet file (style.css), you can use javascript to load this style dynamically with few lines of code: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/524696/how-to-create-a-style-tag-with-javascript/524717#524717. You can also do as you said. You can call javascript which dynamically creates the style "tag by tag", "attribute by attribute" - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/524696/how-to-create-a-style-tag-with-javascript/524715#524715. See the question which I pointed to for many possibilities.