# set attribute for dynamically created class not working in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

http://jsfiddle.net/55Lht7hu/

I am trying to add a attribute (dynamically created) to a div. But it is not working here.

```
var style3=createElement('style');
style3.type="text/css";
var target3=document.getElementById('target3');
target3.addEventListener('click',function(){

style3.innerHTML='.target4{background-color:#444;}';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style3);
target3.setAttribute('class','target4');

});
```

Also, is it possible to set pseudo elements dynamically to that div?.

Comment: Also, shouldn't it be `document.createElement('style');`?

Comment: @PeterKA it is if you just want to add that as text inside the style3 element

Comment: You may want to see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/524696/how-to-create-a-style-tag-with-javascript

Comment: what should it be then instead of innerHTML? innerHTML worked for me before.

Comment: @PeterKA Not sure what you mean, it's perfectly valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all there is no such global function `createElement`, you should use method of the document object:

```
var style3 = document.createElement('style');
```

Then, in order your new background color to be applied, you need to make rule priority higher, because class selector `.target4` will not beat id selector `#target3`. You can increase selector weight for example by prefixing it with corresponding element id selector: `#target3.target4`.

Final clean up, you can drop `style3.type="text/css";` as it's anyway default type for `style` element.

All together:

```js
var style3 = document.createElement('style');
var target3 = document.getElementById('target3');
target3.addEventListener('click', function () {
    style3.innerHTML = '#target3.target4 {background-color:#444;}';
    document.head.appendChild(style3);
    target3.setAttribute('class', 'target4');
});
```

```css
#target3 {
    width:100px;
    height:200px;
    background:red;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="target3"></div>
</body>
```