# Set `overflow: hidden` for every element

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there anyway in Javascript I can set every element to have the CSS property `overflow: hidden`?

I want to do exactly this:

```
* {overflow: hidden}
```

But with Javascript, and **not** JQuery.

I also want this to work if a new element is created on the page, like it would if I used CSS as in the example above.

Comment: why not just add that to the page as a css rule, via javascript?  the css engine already does this work for you, and doing it manually is hugely painful and error-prone.

Comment: Make this with javascript is saturating the cpu processor stupidly. CSS makes  exactly what you said.

Comment: And agree with make it is painful and buggie.

Comment: @Eevee Look at my answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/524696/how-to-create-a-style-tag-with-javascript  http://jonraasch.com/blog/javascript-style-node

Comment: Why a downvote without an explaination?

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer:

```
var style = document.createElement("style");
style.type = "text/css";
style.innerHTML = "* { overflow: hidden; }";
document.head.appendChild(style);
```

The most efficient I can think of.

Comment: is `"* { overflow: hidden; }"`  HTML?

Comment: @SheraliTurdiyev, they are creating a style element, and this is adding the style rules to the body of the style element. Though `textContent`/`innerText` is more the proper property to use since as you question it is not html

Comment: this is exactly what i was suggesting, yes  :)