# How modify a property of external CSS file using jQuery / Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to change a property of external CSS file using `javascript/jquery`

Example; in the  of the web page I'm using:

```
<!-- Star rating -->
<link href="css/star-rating.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

And I want to access and change the color of specific style (Found in the external CSS):

[image: CSS]

Exists a method using JavaScript or jQuery to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a <style> tag with Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/524696/how-to-create-a-style-tag-with-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I create a js method to achieve this:

```
function getStyleSheet(cssName, rule) {
    for (i = 0; i < document.styleSheets.length; i++) {
        if (document.styleSheets[i].href.toString().indexOf(cssName) != -1)
            for (x = 0; x < document.styleSheets[i].rules.length; x++) {
                if (document.styleSheets[i].rules[x].selectorText.toString().indexOf(rule) != -1)
                    return document.styleSheets[i].rules[x];
            }

    }

    return null;
}
```

To change any property only is required the following:

```
getStyleSheet('star-rating', '.rating-container .rating-stars').style.color = "#AFAFAF";
```

Comment: that's great..exactly i was looking for. Could you please help how can I download or copy the updated css to new file.

TIA

Comment: I have the same question, how can I download or copy the updated css to new file as I am unable to find these changes in sources also.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, let's analyze this....

You want to change a CSS rule on your code.
I asume you want to do it as a response to something that happens in the browser...

Change physically the line in the CSS file is not impossible, but I supose that it isn't what you are looking for.

The best option, probably would be to change the CSS style through javascript as a reaction to the event or situation that makes you want to change the style. Using jquery:

```
$(".rating-container").css("color", "#f0f");
```

As an alternative, use different CSS classes for different element states and just change classes into your js code:

```
$("#myAffectedElement").removeClass("oldColorClass");
$("#myAffectedElement").addClass("newColorClass");
```

This will allow you to modify directly individual elements styles instead of changing every originally classed element.