# jQuery change values in a class

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to use jQuery to set values inside a class? So for example if I have a class like this:

```
.menubar {
background: #333;
color: #fff;
}
```

Can I then run something like:

```
$('.menubar').css('background', '#999');
```

... to set the value of that class to #999? And I don't mean to select all the elements with the class and set their background, I mean can I change the actual classes value to #999 so that if an element is created later with the class it will have #999 instead of #333.

Comment: Not with that command, no.

Comment: Is there a similar command? Or another non-jquery way of doing it?

Comment: See the duplicate.

Comment: @SimonHyll what do you mean by "that if an element is created later with the class"  later when ? is there a function creating them ?

Comment: Yes. I'm using Vue.js and it creates and destroys elements all, the, time.

Comment: Stylesheets are accessible through DOM (document.styleSheets) so you can change the actual stylesheet with javascript if you like but is asking for trouble - see for instance the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33784443/how-modify-a-property-of-external-css-file-using-jquery-javascript#answer-33784486