# How to import css dynamically with js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax, eval

I got some condition, so I can not load some css, js in html. So I decide that pulling dynamically with `$.get()`. However, I tested `js` case, but do not have any clues in case of `css`.

Following is pulling and execute `js` from remote CDN dynamically.

Pulling and Execute
    
    https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js'>

Is it possible to get Other javascript file from remote?

```
<pre>
    <code class='java'>
        System.out.println("It's done!");
    </code>
</pre>

<script>
    const highlightCDN = 'http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.2.0/highlight.min.js';
    $(function(){
        $.get(highlightCDN, function(data){
            console.log('done!');
            eval(data);
        }).done(function(){
            $('pre code').each(function(i, block){
                console.log(i);
                hljs.highlightBlock(block);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

However, I can not use `eval` on `css`. What can I do? Is it even possible?
Thanks so much!

P.S. If I pulling `js` like my example, can I use it globally after once I pulled this?

Comment: Is your CSS in a .css file?
(I think you can dinamically create a <link rel...> tag

Comment: see [this question[(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/524696/how-to-create-a-style-tag-with-javascript) for more options

Comment: Thanks, guys. My brain was stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert a link element via jQuery, which points to your external css file like this:

```
$('head').append($('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />').attr('href', 'external-css-stylesheet-url-goes-here'));
```

Comment: Yeap. Thanks. I was idiot -_-; I've been trying to execute `css` for an hour. Thanks a lot!!