# Is there a javascript library that reads a style string and adds the appropriate styles to given elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am looking for a library/code that reads styles for the elements from a string and then applies the styles to the elements in that string. For example consider this code:

```
jsLibrary.setStyle("body{width:90%}div{background:red}.blue{color:bule}");
```

I want this library to read the string passed to it as parameter and then set the styles for `body`, `div`, and `.blue`.

does such a thing exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a library or any complicated parsing code to do this - you can simply insert a `<style>` element with the relevant text - the browser will parse and use it as normal.

```js
var s = document.createElement('style');
s.innerText = "body{width:90%}div{background:red}.blue{color:blue}";
document.body.appendChild(s)
```

```html
<div>abc</div>
<div class="blue">xyz</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just append a `style`-element to your document. See this answer: [How to create a <style> tag with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/524696/how-to-create-a-style-tag-with-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Just create a new Style tag and paste your CSS code there:

### **native javascript:**

```
function addStyle(css) {
    var head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
    var style = document.createElement('style');

    style.type = 'text/css';
    if (style.styleSheet){
      style.styleSheet.cssText = css;
    } else {
      style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
    }

    head.appendChild(style);
}
```

### Jquery:

```
function addStyle(css) {
    $("head").append("<style type='text/css'>"+css+"</style>");
}
```