# How to add styling to output text?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Following code swaps the text after 5 second to some other text, which is implemented using JavaScript. I want to make the output text ( "outputtext1" and "outputtext2") look bigger like a heading, having orange color, and center aligned. How to do that?

The swapping of text works perfectly, there's no problem in the JavaScript code.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      div.textContent {
        display: none
      }

    </style>

    <div id="textMessage"></div>
    <div class="textContent">
      <h2>"outputtext1"</h2></span>
    </div>
    <div class="textContent">
      <h2>"outputtext2"</h2></span>
    </div>

    <script>
      var cnt = 0,
        texts = [];

      // save the texts in an array for re-use
      $(".textContent").each(function() {
        texts[cnt++] = $(this).text();
      });

      function slide() {
        if (cnt >= texts.length) cnt = 0;
        $('#textMessage').html(texts[cnt++]);
        $('#textMessage')
          .fadeIn('slow').animate({
            opacity: 1.0
          }, 5000).fadeOut('slow',
            function() {
              return slide()
            }
          );
      }
      slide()
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: HOW TO DO THAT ? - with CSS, what have you tried?

Comment: Please check this link:-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/524696/how-to-create-a-style-tag-with-javascript

Comment: Ofcourse : I tried to add css, but when I run it, it doesn't work. (  @Velimir )

Answer (score 0):

You can set some style thanks to simple css :

```
.textContent h2 {
  color:orange;
  text-align:center
  font-size: 40px; /* you can increase this value*/;
}
```

Becareful though because your HTML semantic seems incorrect :

```
<div class="textContent" ><h2>"outputtext1"</h2></div>
```

Notice the removal of the < span> tag. Notice also that this is very very simple use case of CSS, so if you need more about it, you better have a look at some documentation such as Mozilla one.

Hope this helped

Comment: With that display: none removed in that css , though it works but not on the text that is swapping. To get better idea , look at this : http://jsfiddle.net/KepBX/117/

Answer (score 0):

```js
var cnt=0, texts=[];

// save the texts in an array for re-use
$(".textContent").each(function() {
  texts[cnt++]=$(this).text();
});
function slide() {
  if (cnt>=texts.length) cnt=0;
  $('#textMessage').html(texts[cnt++]);
  $('#textMessage')
    .fadeIn('slow').animate({opacity: 1.0}, 5000).fadeOut('slow', 
     function() {
       return slide()
     }
  );      
}      
slide()
```

```css
.textContent {
  display:none;
}

#textMessage {
  font-size: 2em;
  color: orange;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="textMessage"></div>

<div class="textContent" ><h2>"outputtext1"</h2></span> </div>
<div class="textContent" ><h2>"outputtext2"</h2></span> </div>
```

Comment: Perfect. I was applying CSS to ".textContent" instead of "#textMessage". Works : http://jsfiddle.net/KepBX/118/

Answer (score 0):

You would want to edit the class, something like this:

```
<style>
div.textContent { color:orange;font-size:20px;display:none }
</style>
```

Just a suggestion, but you probably don't need to have so much nesting here:

```
<div class="textContent" ><h2>"outputtext1"</h2></span> </div>
<div class="textContent" ><h2>"outputtext2"</h2></span> </div>
```

Something like this would probably work better:

```
<h2 class="textContent">"outputtext1"</h2>
<h2 class="textContent">"outputtext2"</h2>
```

Comment: I had already tried this. but it doesn't work like that. Look : http://jsfiddle.net/KepBX/116/

Comment: Try this - is this what you're looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/5L4dng2t/

Answer (score 0):

```js
var cnt=0, texts=[];

// save the texts in an array for re-use
$(".textContent").each(function() {
  texts[cnt++]=$(this).text();
});
function slide() {
  if (cnt>=texts.length) cnt=0;
  $('#textMessage').html("<h1>"+texts[cnt++]+"</h1>");
  $('#textMessage')
    .fadeIn('slow').animate({opacity: 1.0}, 5000).fadeOut('slow', 
     function() {
       return slide()
     }
  );      
}      
slide()
```

```css
#textMessage {
  text-align: center;
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="textMessage"></div>

<div class="textContent"><h2>outputtext1</h2></span> </div>
<div class="textContent"><h2>outputtext2</h2></span> </div>
```

There are 3 steps to your solution - [Codepen here](http://codepen.io/PleaseBugMeNot/pen/zovdJX)

1) Remove the unwanted `""` from `<h2>"outputtext1"</h2>`. Keep it `<h2>outputtext1</h2>`

2) Centering & color can be done via CSS

```
#textMessage {
  text-align: center;
  color: orange;
}
```

3) Now the heading, you need to make a small change to your javascript -- `$('#textMessage').html("<h1>"+texts[cnt++]+"</h1>");`

```
function slide() {
  if (cnt>=texts.length) cnt=0;
  $('#textMessage').html("<h1>"+texts[cnt++]+"</h1>"); //changed
  $('#textMessage')
    .fadeIn('slow').animate({opacity: 1.0}, 5000).fadeOut('slow', 
     function() {
       return slide()
     }
  );      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply CSS to `#textMessage`, like:

```
#textMessage {
  font-size: 38px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: orange;
}
```

```js
var cnt=0, texts=[];

// save the texts in an array for re-use
$(".textContent").each(function() {
  texts[cnt++]=$(this).text();
});

function slide() {
  if (cnt>=texts.length) cnt=0;
  $('#textMessage').html(texts[cnt++]);
  $('#textMessage')
    .fadeIn('slow').animate({opacity: 1.0}, 5000).fadeOut('slow', 
     function() {
       return slide()
     }
  );      
}      
slide()
```

```css
#textMessage {
  font-size: 38px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: orange;
}

body {
  padding: 20px;
}

.textContent {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="textMessage"></div>

<div class="textContent" ><h2>"outputtext1"</h2></span> </div>
<div class="textContent" ><h2>"outputtext2"</h2></span> </div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: div.textContent {
        display: none } 

Is must. you forgot that, otherwise, perfect. Helped.

Comment: @JayAkbariPixmercy Updated my answer, please have a look, if this answer helped you, you may accept it.