# WebExtension - Inject CSS on <head> that might change/isn't unique

Tags: javascript, ajax, firefox-addon-webextensions

My WebExtension has options, such as "hide footer". Problem is that I can't manipulate DOM on `document_start`, because the `<footer>` doesn't exist yet. Injecting the code on `document_end` works, but the users still see the footer for a few seconds.

I have tried injecting CSS on `<head>` using `document_start` and it worked well. Now my question is:

- Since CSS won't always be the same, what would be the best way to inject CSS? Is there a JavaScript function to directly write CSS to `<style>`, or should that be written manually using something such as innerHTML?

Comment: You can use createTextNode http://stackoverflow.com/a/524721/414062

Comment: @DominicTobias Thanks, that method is much cleaner than my innerHTML method.

Comment: @DominicTobias & Qluvy, Rather than explicitly creating a text node with `style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));`, it is more efficient to just assign to the [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) property like: `style.textContent = css;`. Note: "Setting this property on a node removes all of its children and replaces them with a single text node with the given value." In the case of a `<style>` element, this is desirable. Unlike assigning to `.innerHTML`, the text is not interpreted as HTML, just text.

Comment: Asking for the "best" way to do something is usually considered opinion based, and often leads to a question being closed. I would suggest you reword.

Comment: It's not clear why the `<footer>` not existing has anything to do with your ability to manipulate the DOM on `document_start`. Please explain why this is a problem. Yes, much of the DOM does not exist on `document_start`, that the point of using `document_start`. Are you aware you can add your `<style>` to the `document.documentElement` prior to the `<head>` and `<body>` existing? Please explain your requirements in detail, so that it is more clear which of the ways to inject dynamic CSS would be more appropriate (e.g `tabs.insertCSS()`, using a content script to insert `<style>` element(s)).

Comment: @Makyen Thank you for your reply, I have reworded the question a bit.

Comment: @Makyen The problem is that most DOM parts don't exist on document_start, meaning I have to add CSS on <head> to hide some tags such as footer. Depending on the settings, users can remove the footer and other parts of the website, but I have to do that on document_end, meaning they will still see these elements for a few seconds until it gets removed.