# How to clear all the css for a div and it's child elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div element and it has some child elements. For this div and it's child elements css is applying from external css file.

I want to clear all the css for the div and it's child elements. and I want to write own css only for this div.

Is it possible?

Comment: Just apply your own style and make it important...

Comment: This might help you [Specificity-CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

Comment: Short answer: it is. Longer answer: one of the options is to create a style tag with the necessary rules and append it to head.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a <style> tag with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/524696/how-to-create-a-style-tag-with-javascript)

Comment: I don't want to override each and every css propery. is there any way clear all the css for div and it's child elements in one shot.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your stylesheet comes after the stylesheet from where the elements inherit the styles.
Then you just have to overwrite the styles making sure there are no specificity issues.