# Change style of list's bullet

Tags: reactjs, draftjs

I have a draft-js component. I can add styles into StyleMap (via adding new objects into customStyleMap). However when I have a selected list and change size, it only changes size of the selected text - bullets are still same. I know I can change style of block with `blockStyleFn={getBlockStyle}` but here I have two problems:

1. As far I know, it only works with already defined classes - but I can't have classes for every size. How can I dynamically add class?
2. How can I get style out of block?

So in `getBlockStyle(block)` I have to do something like this:

```
let style = block.getStyleOfContent(); //for example returns fontSize: '16px'
addNewClass('listFontSize16px', style); //add new class
return listFontSize16px;
```

Or any other solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figure it out...

1. [How to create a <style> tag with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/524696/how-to-create-a-style-tag-with-javascript)
2. In `getBlockStyle(block)` block contains a key. Thanks to the key I can find the same key in content of editorState and there is the style.

It is not the nicest solution but it works pretty good.