# Manipulate CSS classes with vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, drop-down-menu, dom-manipulation

Is there a way to manipulate a CSS class with plain JavaScript?

I am creating a dropdown-menu and I want to transition it from `height: 0` to the computed height of the element when `height: auto`.

**By default, the CSS class that I'm trying to manipulate does not have an element.**

---

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="dropdown-parent">
  <li><a>Link</a></li>
  <li>
    <a>Link</a>
    <ul class="dropdown">
      <li>Link</li>
      <li>Link</li>
      <li>Link</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
.dropdown-parent {
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 100%;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: height 1s ease-in-out;
}

.expand {}
```

JavaScript:

```
const dropdown = document.querySelector('.dropdown-parent');
const dropdownList = document.querySelector('.dropdown');

dropdownList.style.height = 'auto';
const dropdownHeight = dropdownList.offsetHeight;
dropdownList.style.height = '0';

dropdown.addEventListener('click', () => {
    -- TRYING TO ADD CALCULATED HEIGHT TO THE CLASS '.expand' --

    dropdown.classList.toggle('expand');
});
```

---

**I want to:**

1) Fetch the element in the DOM.

2) Set the element's height to auto.

3) Calculate it's height and store it in a variable.

4) Set it's height back to 0.

5) Add the calculated height to the class `.expand`.

6) Add an event listener to the parent to toggle the class `.expand`.

The only thing I cannot do is the step (5).

Some help on this topic?

Comment: You can't modify the .expand class without a) modifying the .css stylesheet or b) adding another <style> element to over-write the existing styles. Would it be okay to inject inline styles as you have already done? If you're dead set on pursuing your current methodology you might want to look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/524696/how-to-create-a-style-tag-with-javascript

Answer (score 1):

You can probably solve this by using [CSS custom properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*) to change the value itself.

CSS:

```
:root {
  --expanded-height: auto;
}

.expand {
  height: var(--expanded-height);
}
```

Javascript:

```
dropdown.addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--expanded-height', dropdownHeight);
    dropdown.classList.toggle('expand');
});
```

Source: [CSS Custom Properties—Dynamic Changes With And Without Javascript](https://vanseodesign.com/css/custom-properties-and-javascript/)

Answer (score 0):

You can create new element `style` in the DOM and declare `.expand {}` class

```
const dropdown = document.querySelector('.dropdown-parent');
const dropdownList = document.querySelector('.dropdown');

dropdownList.style.height = 'auto';
const dropdownHeight = dropdownList.offsetHeight;
dropdownList.style.height = '0';

let sheet = document.createElement('style');
document.body.appendChild(sheet);

dropdown.addEventListener('click', () => {
    sheet.innerHTML = ".expand {height: " + dropdownHeight + "px;}";
    dropdown.classList.toggle('expand');
});
```

Even if predefined class `.expand` exists, this statement will just append or redefine property `height` of class `.expand`.
Depending on context you should avoid of duplicate creating the element `sheet`.