# Change text highlight color in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

In CSS, in order to change the highlight color, you add the following:

```
element::selection { color: red; }
```

How can you set the `::selection` css attribute in JavaScript?

Comment: I guess using inline styles is the only option.

Comment: the formating attributes are deprecated.

Comment: @DanielA.White how can you set the `::selection` css attribute in javascript? The question you marked as a dupe does not address that.

Comment: oh i didn't know thats what you were going for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a `style` element and place it in the `head` with the appropriate CSS that you need. A variation on: https://stackoverflow.com/a/524721/23528

```
var css = 'element::selection { color: red; }',
    head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
    style = document.createElement('style');

style.type = 'text/css';
if (style.styleSheet){
  // This is required for IE8 and below.
  style.styleSheet.cssText = css;
} else {
  style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
}

head.appendChild(style);
```