# How to load @font-face in dynamically loaded styles of Web Component with shadow DOM

Tags: html, css

I have a HTML 5 WebComponent with shadow DOM which displays content that has to load styles depending on the content type that is displayed in the component. The list of stylesheets is fetched from the server.

I can load the stylesheets like this:

```js
for (const style of styles) {
    const stylesheet = document.createElement('link');
    stylesheet.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
    stylesheet.setAttribute('href', style);
    stylesheet.setAttribute('type', 'text/css');
    this.root.appendChild(stylesheet);
}
```

However, the stylesheets sometimes also include `@font-face` rules, which are not added to the component. The browser never creates requests for the fonts references in the `@font-face` rules. How can I load these rules dynamically?

Comment: This issue doesn't appear on Safari, but is a known issue on [Chrome](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=336876) and [Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1077396)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turned out that browsers don't support loading `@font-face` CSS rules in shadow DOMs as of September 2020. The Chrome team seems to be working on this, though.

The approach I took was to look for `@font-face` rules in the dynamically created stylesheet, modify them a bit to get relative paths working and then add them to the `<head>` of the page with a script. If you add the `@font-face` rules to the head **and** the shadow DOM, the fonts will be loaded and applied.

Here's the code:

```js
for (const style of styles) { // styles is an array of urls
    const stylesheet = document.createElement('link');
    stylesheet.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
    stylesheet.setAttribute('href', style);
    stylesheet.setAttribute('type', 'text/css');
    stylesheet.onload = (event) => {
        for (
            let i = 0;
            i < event.currentTarget.sheet.cssRules.length;
            i++
        ) {
            if (event.currentTarget.sheet.cssRules[i].type == 5) { // type 5 is @font-face
                const split = style.split('/');
                const stylePath = split
                    .slice(0, split.length - 1)
                    .join('/');
                let cssText =
                    event.currentTarget.sheet.cssRules[i].cssText;
                cssText = cssText.replace(
                    // relative paths
                    /url\s*\(\s*[\'"]?(?!((\/)|((?:https?:)?\/\/)|(?:data\:?:)))([^\'"\)]+)[\'"]?\s*\)/g,
                    `url("${stylePath}/$4")`
                );

                const st = document.createElement('style');
                st.appendChild(document.createTextNode(cssText));
                document
                    .getElementsByTagName('head')[0]
                    .appendChild(st);
            }
        }
    };
    this.root.appendChild(stylesheet);
}
```

It works fine on Edge 85 (Chromium based).

Comment: Hacky but works great, thank you

Comment: I tried for almost 5 hours fixing this solution in shadow dom and then finally got this link. Can you tell why font-face is not working in shadow dom? Any link which explains the reason?

Comment: > The Chrome team seems to be working on this, though
How do you know? Any progress on this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that but you can create a `<style>` element with JavaScript

[Code from #524696](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/524696/how-to-create-a-style-tag-with-javascript#524721)

```js
var css = 'h1 { background: red; }',
    head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
    style = document.createElement('style');

head.appendChild(style);

style.type = 'text/css';
if (style.styleSheet){
  // This is required for IE8 and below.
  style.styleSheet.cssText = css;
} else {
  style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
}
```

Comment: I've tried your suggestion and the result is the same: the stylesheets load and display fine, but the fonts added with @font-face are not loaded

Comment: I tested this in codepen and the @font-face fonts is loaded correctly

Comment: Turns out that the problem is that the shadow DOM inside the Web Component doesn‘t load the font face. If I turn it off and load the stylesheets globally, the font faces are loaded. Seems to be a limitation of the shadow dom. Whether you load the styles with a style or link tag doesn‘t matter on modern browsers, though.

Comment: You can load fonts in @font-face url in CSS, its better solution than `@import`

Comment: I don't use @import