# GoogleFont in LitElement ShadowDOM

Tags: css, shadow-dom, lit-element, google-fonts

I'm creating a component in LitELement, with ShadowDOM, where I want to display an icon from GoogleFonts' Material Symbols Outlined.

In index.html, I am using this url:

```
https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outline
```

as a regular css link:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

And it works fine when I drop something like

```
<span class="material-symbols-outlined">
  search
</span>
```

directly in index.html. But when I move it into the ShadowDOM component, it doesn't work. So, assuming that the index.html `<link>` has to stay in index.html in order to provide `@font-face`, I've tried to inject the stylesheet into the ShadowDOM to provide the class declaration (`.material-symbols-outlined`) - in three ways:

1. Via css import:

   ```
   @customElement('my-comp')
   export class MyComponent extends LitElement {
     static styles = [
       css`
         @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined");
       `
     ];

     render() {
       return html`
         <span class="material-symbols-outlined">search</span>
       `;
     }
   }
   ```
2. Via link in render:

   ```
   @customElement('my-comp')
   export class MyComponent extends LitElement {
     render() {
       const iconsCssLink = html`
         <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined" rel="stylesheet"/>
       `;

       return html`
         ${iconsCssLink}
         <span class="material-symbols-outlined">search</span>
       `;
     }
   }
   ```
3. Via a shared component containing styles only:

   ```
    @customElement('icon-styles')
    export class IconStylesComponent extends LitElement {
      static styles = [
        css`
          @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined");
        `
      ];
    }
   ```

   and then importing it into the target component with ShadowDOM:

   ```
   @customElement('my-comp')
   export class MyComponent extends LitElement {
     static styles = [
       IconStylesComponent.styles,
     ];

     render() {
       return html`
         <span class="material-symbols-outlined">search</span>
       `;
     }
   }
   ```

None of these methods worked. Which piece of the puzzle am I missing?

Comment: I found this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63717709). Hacky, but works. Still, if anyone knows a more modern solution - I'd love to hear

Answer (score 0):

Just use `@conectate/ct-icon`

```
npm i @conectate/ct-icon
```

### Usage

```
import { LitElement, html, css } from 'lit';
import '@conectate/ct-icon'

@customElement('Untitled-1')
export class UNtitled1 extends LitElement {
    static styles = [
        css`
            :host {
                display: block;
            }
        `
    ];

    render() {
        return html`<ct-icon icon="account"></ct-icon>`;
    }
}
```