# Can fonts be imported from within the shadow DOM with a `<style>` tag?

Tags: css, fonts, shadow-dom

Can a font be imported from within the shadow dom and have it apply to its children?

When trying to do something like

```js
class MyCustomElement extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    const shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
    shadowRoot.innerHTML = `
      <style>
        @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans');
        :host {
          font-family: 'Open Sans';
        }
      </style>
      <h1>Hello font?</h1>
    `;
  }
}
customElements.define('my-custom-element', MyCustomElement);
```

The font isn't being applied to the `<h1>`. The CSS inspector shows `<h1>`'s font computed as `"Open Sans"`. In the network tab, Chrome requests the stylesheet, but Firefox does not. In both browsers it renders with a system default font.

What's missing to make this work?

The full HTML file is,

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/vite.svg" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Font test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      class MyCustomElement extends HTMLElement {
        constructor() {
          super();
          const shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({ mode: "open" });
          shadowRoot.innerHTML = `
      <style>
        @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans');
        :host {
          font-family: 'Open Sans';
        }
      </style>
      <h1>Hello font?</h1>
    `;
        }
      }
      customElements.define("my-custom-element", MyCustomElement);
    </script>
    <my-custom-element></my-custom-element>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Firefox**

[image: Firefox example]

**Chrome**

[image: Chrome example]

Comment: I tried loading your js file in my HTML file and it's able to show the font on h1 tag with above code. So can you please share how you are calling or implementing this code in your file ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, hope you will find new knowledge here. You can help us answering your question, by adding a [minimal-reproducible-example StackOverflow Snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with the [< >] button in the editor. It will help readers execute your code with one click. And help create answers with one click. Thank you.

Comment: I agree with @Kaiido. It works for me as well. Just one more thing I want to confirm is that you are directly running this file on browser or you are loading it using javascript ?

Comment: Added screenshots to facilitate the discussion. The file is a pure HTML file loaded directly in the browser.

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman thanks for the suggestion, I've added a code snippet, the issue is reproducible with the code snippet.

Comment: Not sure what I saw earlier, I was clearly mistaken. As per [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63710162/how-to-load-font-face-in-dynamically-loaded-styles-of-web-component-with-shadow) it's indeed impossible to set font-face declaration in shadow DOM, but I can't find what they're referring to when they say Chrome is working on it.. Still, if you're ok with it being marked as duplicate, let me know: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63710162/how-to-load-font-face-in-dynamically-loaded-styles-of-web-component-with-shadow

Comment: @Kaiido thanks for pointing out that question. I believe indeed that we're asking the same thing in both q's. Happy to mark this one as a dupe, although wish the other one was better documented with a code snippet / screenshots :)

Comment: Oh, I can't vote anymore, I already did when I thought it was not reproducible... Someone should doit then. And, yes I agree the answer there could be improved.

Answer (score 0):

When you use '@import' within a Shadow DOM, it doesn't always work as expected due to the timing of when the styles are applied.
In your case, the '@import' rule might not be applied in time for the font-family declaration .

```
class MyCustomElement extends HTMLElement {
      constructor() {
       super();
       const link = document.createElement('link');
       link.rel = 'stylesheet';
       link.href = 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans';
       document.head.appendChild(link);
       const shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
                    shadowRoot.innerHTML = `
                      <style>
                        :host {
                          font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
                        }
                      </style>
                      <h1>Hello font?</h1>
                    `;
                  }
                }
  customElements.define('my-custom-element', MyCustomElement);
```

Comment: Timing of what?

Comment: I meant the order in which the browser loads and applies stylesheets and renders elements

Comment: Still not clearer. Why would that prevent the font from being applied?

Answer (score 0):

You have to *register* an external Font both in the Global Scope and in the Web Component

```html
<script>
customElements.define('my-element', class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
  
    let href = "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans";

    super().attachShadow({mode:'open'})
           .innerHTML = `<style>@import url('${href}')</style>` +
           `<style>:host{font-family:'Open Sans'}</style>` + 
           `<h1>Hello Font: </h1>`;

    // make sure font is globally loaded
    let fontExist = 
        //document.fonts.check("32px Open Sans");
        document.querySelector(`link[href="${href}"]`);
    if (!fontExist) {
      console.log("append LINK font");
      document.head.append(
        Object.assign(document.createElement("link"), {
          rel: "stylesheet",
          href,
          onload : () => this.fontloaded()
        }))
    } else {
      this.fontloaded();
    } 
  }

  fontloaded(){
    let h1 = this.shadowRoot.querySelector("h1");
    h1.innerHTML += getComputedStyle(h1).font;
    this.hidden = false;
    console.log(document.fonts.check('0px Open Sans'));
  }
});
</script>
<my-element hidden></my-element>
```

Comment: Better check with `document.fonts` rather than this queySelector that will miss all `@import`. And you don't need to declare it in both, you just must set it in the global scope.

Comment: Good addition, probably have to check with ``document.fonts.check("32px Open Sans");`` then

Comment: No, unfortunately `.check()` doesn't help here (bad design IMO). You'd need to do something like `[...document.fonts].find(({family}) => family === '"Open Sans"')`.

Comment: There's no need to register the font within the custom element when already registered at the document level.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you may also add a new font via [CSS font loading API method `FontFace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS_Font_Loading_API) like so.

```css
h1 {
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  font-weight: 800;
  font-stretch: 75%;
}
```

```html
<script>
  class MyCustomElement extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      super();
      const shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({
        mode: "open"
      });
      //Define a FontFace
      const font = new FontFace("Open Sans", "url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v40/mem8YaGs126MiZpBA-UFVZ0b.woff2)", {
        style: "normal",
        weight: "400",
        stretch: "75% 100%"
      });
      
      // wait for font 
      font.load().then( (loaded_face)=> {
        document.fonts.add(loaded_face)
        
        // append content
        shadowRoot.innerHTML = `
      <style>
        :host {
          font-family: 'Open Sans';
          font-weight: 300;
          font-stretch: 75%;
        }
      </style>
      <h1>Hello font?</h1>
    `;
      }).catch((error)=>{});
    }
  }
  customElements.define("my-custom-element", MyCustomElement);
</script>
<my-custom-element></my-custom-element>

<hr>

<h1>Title in parent document</h1>
```

Keep in mind, this method actually adds the font to the global scope – see 2nd heading in example also using "Open Sans".

This approach also requires to extract the actual font file URL from the google fonts API query.

However, we can quite reliably check if/when the font is loaded – which is handy for many rendering tasks e.g drawing text with a custom font to canvas.