# NuxtJS Content Security Policy

Tags: http-headers, nuxt.js, content-security-policy, cloudflare-workers

Unable to apply a content security policy without including unsafe-inline for scripts and styles.
NuxtJS generates both inline styles and scripts upon build.

As my **application is static**, NuxtJS default configuration for this does not work as it requires Server side rendering to achieve this. I haven't been able to find a way to inject a nonce into the build process to solve this issue.

My current setup is to apply Security HTTP Headers to the domain is using a cloudflare worker which does not touch the application. Therefore I am looking for options how to integrate this between the application and edge worker *https://scotthelme.co.uk/csp-nonces-the-easy-way-with-cloudflare-workers/*

Came across couple of injecting methods using middleware while browsing nuxtjs github issues which I can't get to work.

Has anyone found a solution for generating a policy which does not include unsafe-inline, either directly in the application or externally?

Answer (score 0):

> NuxtJS generates both inline styles and scripts upon build. ... I haven't been able to find a way to inject a nonce into the build process to solve this issue

From the point of view of the CSP

- there are [3 types](https://csplite.com/csp147/) inline scripts and **only 1** of them may be allowed using 'nonce-value'
- there are [3 types](https://csplite.com/csp146/#inline_css_api) on inline styles (including JS call of `.setAttribute()` function - yeah it's requires 'unsafe-inline' in style-src too), and **only 1** of them may be allowed using 'nonce-value'.

Therefore, in an abstract form, your task is not solvable, you need specifics.

Assuming you are only using `<script>...</script>` and `<style>...</style>` constructs (these may be allowed using 'nonce-value') you have 3 options:

1. use 'nonce-value'
2. use 'hash-value'
3. place script/style into external file and use 'self'

In case of usage [document.createElement('style')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/524696/how-to-create-a-style-tag-with-javascript), opt 1 is preferable you just set `style.nonce = 'generated_base64_value'` attribute. Because to calculate 'hash-value' is not easy in this case.

In case of usage `<script>...</script>` and `<style>...</style>` much easier to calculate hashes or move all to external file (opts 2, 3). To use cloudflare workers is complicate the code unnecessarily in this case.

Some middleware generates a lot of separate `<style>.red {color:red;}</style>`, `<style>.r_padd {padding-right:20px;}</style>`, etc. It is a headache for opts 1, 2, but easy solvable via opt 3.

If you use third-party scripts, for example Google Tag Manager, there is no way to get rid of 'unsafe-inline' scripts, and from 'unsafe-eval' too in some cases.

PS: There is no universal way. And not knowing what is under the hood of your car, it is difficult to give advice on how to afterburner it.