# How to change link color by using only JavaScript not CSS or HTML

Tags: javascript

I want to change the BOOK link to red color. how can I change it by JavaScript without adding an id or class? I tried using sections but it's not working. Thanks.

```js
var sections = document.getElementsByClassName('section');
sections.getElementsByTagName("a")[2].style.color="red";
sections.getElementsByTagName("li")[2].style.color="red";
```

```html
<section>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">1</a></li>
    </ul>
 </section>
 <section>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">2</a></li>
    </ul>
 </section>
 <section>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">3</a></li>
    </ul>
 </section>

<section>
    <div class="Search-view">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Search</a></li>
            <li><a href="">View </a></li>
            <!-- change book to red -->
            <li><a href="">Book</a></li> 
            <li><a href="">Sell</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Get</a></li> 
        </ul>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: `sections` is an HTML collection

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/524696/how-to-create-a-style-tag-with-javascript has a great method to inject CSS -- you can simply target the appropriate selector with css nth-child: `section .Search-view ul li:nth-child(2) a { color: red; };`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Issue

`.getElementsByClassName('section')` is used although there is no tag with class `.section`. It gets nothing.

### Solution

```js
// Get all a tags
const allA = document.querySelectorAll('a');

allA.forEach(a => {
  // If text in a tag is 'book'
  if (/^book$/i.test(a.textContent)) {
    // Change color to red
    a.style.color = 'red';
  }
})
```

```html
<section>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">1</a></li>
  </ul>
</section>
<section>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">2</a></li>
  </ul>
</section>
<section>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">3</a></li>
  </ul>
</section>

<section>
  <div class="Search-view">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Search</a></li>
      <li><a href="">View </a></li>
      <!-- change book to red -->
      <li><a href="">Book</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Sell</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Get</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>
```

Personally, I recommend adding an ID to the a tag of 'book' like `<a id="book">Book</a>`.

Answer (score 1):

There are better ways of doing this.. like through css and its `:nth-child()` pseudo selector. But with your code just do this:

```
var sections = document.getElementsByTagName('section');
sections[sections.length-1].getElementsByTagName("li")[2].getElementsByTagName("a")[0].style.color="red";
```

With only CSS just add this ruleset to your stylesheet

```
.Search-view li:nth-child(3) a {
   color: red;
}
```

But ids and classes are you friends. Use them.

Comment: Thanks Zergski, I am trying to practice my js skills, so I want to change it only by js. but i tried your js code, looks not working, could you pls expain more?

Comment: edited answer. sections is a collection and needs an index

Answer (score 1):

I guess you define `section` as a `class` and then you try to override it with `Tag`. Because it said the error is on the second line, so I guess the override fail. Try to remove the class and use the `Tag` on the `section` variable

Comment: OP wants to do this using JavaScript only.