# Dynamically link radio button tabs to content div

Tags: javascript, html, css, dynamic, radio-button

I initially had some tabs created with radio buttons and labels which are linked to corresponding divs using their IDs and was working fine. But the problem is I am now creating the radio button tabs and their corresponding divs dynamically and wish to still allow my css to know which one should be open when a radio button is checked.

My CSS:

```
  #tab-1:checked~.content #content-1,
  #tab-2:checked~.content #content-2,
  #tab-3:checked~.content #content-3,
  #tab-4:checked~.content #content-4,
  #tab-4:checked~.content #content-5 {
      display: block;
  }
```

With the above initially, when the radio button with id of `tab-1` is checked, the div with id of `content-1` is displayed but right now this will no longer work for me as I am now creating the radio buttons dynamically using incoming IDs from my DB like: `#tab-100, #tab-101, #tab-102` and the divs as well `#content-100, #content-101, #content-102`. I need my CSS to be dynamic as well so when `#tab-100` is checked, it automatically displays `#content-100`. I am aware I can do this with javascript but I want to believe that there is a way to do it with CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I later resorted to using javascript and dynamically created a style element.

HTML:

```
<input type="radio" id="tab-231" class="tab" name="number" value="first"><label for="tab-231">First</label><br>
<input type="radio" id="tab-232" class="tab" name="number" value="second"><label for="tab-232">Second</label><br>
<input type="radio" id="tab-233" class="tab" name="number" value="third"><label for="tab-233">Third</label><br>

<div class="tab-content" class="tabs">First content</div>
<div class="tab-content" class="tabs">Second content</div>
<div class="tab-content" class="tabs">Third content</div>
```

JS:

```
const tabs = $('.tabs') //getting all the inputs with class tab
let css = '';

   //dynamically select the tab elements
   for ( const tab of tabs ) {
      const split = tab.id.split('-');
      const id = split[split.length - 1];
      css += `
         #tab-${id}:checked~.content #content-${id},
      `;
   }

   css = css.trim().slice(0, -1) //make sure to remove the trailing ',' in the css text
   css += `
      {
         display: block;
      }
   `;

   //create style element and append to document head
   const style = document.createElement('style');
   document.head.appendChild(style);

   if (style.styleSheet)
      style.styleSheet.cssText = css;
   else
      style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
```

[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/524721/10339262) was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You could give the tab and content elements a class (e.g. `tab` and `tab-content`) and select the desired element with the `:nth-of-type` selector and the corresponding number.

If for example the first tab is checked (`.tab:nth-of-type(1):checked`), select the first content (`.tab-content:nth-of-type(1)`) and make it visible (e.g. `display: block`).

```css
.tab-content {
  display: none;
}

.tab:nth-of-type(1):checked ~ .tab-content:nth-of-type(1),
.tab:nth-of-type(2):checked ~ .tab-content:nth-of-type(2),
.tab:nth-of-type(3):checked ~ .tab-content:nth-of-type(3) {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" id="tab-231" class="tab" name="number" value="first"><label for="tab-231">First</label><br>
<input type="radio" id="tab-232" class="tab" name="number" value="second"><label for="tab-232">Second</label><br>
<input type="radio" id="tab-233" class="tab" name="number" value="third"><label for="tab-233">Third</label><br>

<div class="tab-content">First content</div>
<div class="tab-content">Second content</div>
<div class="tab-content">Third content</div>
```

## Edit

Unfortunately, I am not aware of any CSS-only solution that would automatically provide the desired selectors for the generated elements.

But there is another way how to solve the problem. In this solution, the placement of the `tab` and the `tab-content` are dependent on each other. So *- if your circumstances allow it -* you must always place the `tab-content` after the corresponding `tab`, as you can see in the following example:

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 2rem;
}
.tab-content {;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
.tab:checked ~ .tab-content {
  display: block;
}
.tab:checked ~ .tab-content ~ .tab-content {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
 <div class="wrapper">
 
  <input type="radio" id="tab-231" class="tab" name="number" value="first"><label for="tab-231">First</label><br>
  <div id="tab-231" class="tab-content">First content</div>

  <input type="radio" id="tab-232" class="tab" name="number" value="second"><label for="tab-232">Second</label><br>
  <div id="tab-232" class="tab-content">Second content</div>

  <input type="radio" id="tab-233" class="tab" name="number" value="third"><label for="tab-233">Third</label><br>
  <div id="tab-233" class="tab-content">Third content</div>

</div>
```

Comment: the issue here is I am not certain of the number of data coming in so I cannot possible write the nth-type of all the incoming data hard codedly