# How to add an HTML <style>tag with some css style at the end of my page before </body>

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am looking to add an **HTML**  `<style>` **tag** with some CSS style at the end of my page before `</body>` using pure javascript for this.

```js
var htm = { html : <style>.wrapper {color:red;}</style>}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="tab blue">
  <input id="tab-four" type="radio" name="tabs2">
  <label for="tab-four">Label One</label>
  <div class="tab-content">
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/524721/3200792

Comment: Note that even if you do it with JS, you create an invalid HTML markup. At no point `<style>` within the body is anymore valid since the scope attribute has been deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `beforeeend` position with [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) method.

```js
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<style>.tab-content { color: #bada55; background: black; }</style>');
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="tab blue">
    <input id="tab-four" type="radio" name="tabs2">
    <label for="tab-four">Label One</label>
    <div class="tab-content">Test styling from vanilla JS
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var css = '.wrapper {color:red;}',
body = document.body || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0],
style = document.createElement('style');
body.appendChild(style);
style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
```

Comment: dont use `getElementsByTagName('body')`. Use querySelector instead: `querySelector('body')`

Answer (score 1):

You could use [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) along with [innerText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText):

```js
var stlyings = '.wrapper { color :red }';
var style = document.createElement('style');
style.innerText  = stlyings;
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(style);
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="tab blue">
  <input id="tab-four" type="radio" name="tabs2">
  <label for="tab-four">Label One</label>
  <div class="tab-content">
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: dont use `getElementsByTagName('body')`. Use `querySelector` instead: `querySelector('body')`