# Hiding modals, popups and overlays in Cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

I'm writing Cypress-tests to a site, that has several modals (newsletter signups inside iframe), popups ("Remember free shipping if X, Y and Z") and overlays.

These elements are quite the problem, since it makes it impossible to 'click field A' and fill it out with text: `abcd`. Since the overlays opens on top of the whole thing.

**Overarching question:** How do I get rid of these modals, popups and overlays, so I can interact with the page?

---

### Solution attempt 1: Inject a stylesheet in `beforeEach`, with `display: none;`

I imagined something like this:

```
cy.get('head').then( (head) => {
  let gottenHead = document.head;
  let styles = document.createElement('style');
  styles.type = 'text/css';
  styles.innerHTML = '.iframes-container { display: none !important; }'
  gottenHead.appendChild( styles ); // Doesnt work, 
  head.appendChild( styles ); // Doesnt work
});
```

Or [this gist here], but that doesn't work either, throwing the error: "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'appendChild')" for this line: `doc.body.head.appendChild($style);`.

---

### Solution attempt 2:

Adding a [mutation observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver), checking if any of the wrapping elements gets added to the dom. And if they do - remove them again.

This just again, doesn't seem like 'The Cypress Way'.
So I haven't tried this yet.

---

### Solution attempt 3: Figure out when they open and click 'close' on them

This seems like the most organic approach. But I'd actually rather have a lazy option, that simply hides them all, whenever Cypress is running.

But the problem with this is that the 'close'-button is [inside an iframe, which Cypress doesn't like interacting with](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2020/02/12/working-with-iframes-in-cypress/).

---

### Other info

I checked [Cypress' documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/), but couldn't find any guidelines on how to bypass these modals and popups, weirdly enough.

---

**Update1:** Agoff asked what keeps track of, if the modal/popups should show. I tried checking if a cookie was set, a session variable or some local storage. But I couldn't see anything being added, after 'clicking them away'. :-/

Comment: In the browser, what keeps track of if a user has clicked these popups before? Is it in sesesionStorage/localStorage/cookies?

Comment: Good question. I looked into it - and I couldn't figure out, how it is 'remembered' if they should open or not. I've updated the question (in the bottom).

Comment: I'm not a website expert, but I'm seeing that `document.head` is readonly, and the best way to update that is something like this SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28662118/11625850 . Would something like that make option 1 viable?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the end, it showed that @agoff was actually right. It was save in the local storage.

I wrote these commands that I use to display, save and set the localStorage (using the [cypress-localstorage-commands package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-localstorage-commands) ):

**In Commands:**

```javascript
import "cypress-localstorage-commands"

Cypress.Commands.add( "displayPopupLocalStorage", () => {
  cy.getLocalStorage('THECUSTOMLOCALSTORAGEKEY').then( (localStorageContents) => {
    cy.log( "THECUSTOMLOCALSTORAGEKEY contents: ");
    cy.log( localStorageContents );
  })
});


Cypress.Commands.add( "savePopupLocalStorage", () => {
  cy.getLocalStorage('THECUSTOMLOCALSTORAGEKEY').then( (localStorageContents) => {
    cy.writeFile( "cypress/fixtures/tmp/popup-local-storage.json", localStorageContents );
  })
});


Cypress.Commands.add( "setPopupLocalStorage", () => {
  cy.fixture( "tmp/popup-local-storage.json", 'utf8' )
  .then( (localStorageContents) => {
    cy.setLocalStorage('THECUSTOMLOCALSTORAGEKEY', JSON.stringify( localStorageContents ) );
  });
});
```

**Tests**

```javascript
  it( 'Accept and save pop-up cookies', () => {
    cy.visit( "https://example.org" );

    // Close popup and save local storage
    cy.get( '.popup-wrapper .close-form' ).click()
    cy.wait( 500 ); // Needed for the animation to finish, so the localStorage is set
    cy.savePopupLocalStorage();
  });


  it( 'Sets popup cookies and check that header is clickable', () => {
    cy.setPopupLocalStorage();
    cy.visit( "https://example.org" );
    cy.get('.popup-wrapper', { timeout: 10000 }).should('not.exist');

    // Verify that it works, by going to a page and ensure that the something is clickable
    cy.get( '#header .logo > a' ).then( ($logo) => {
      Cypress.dom.isFocusable( $logo );
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 3):

Delete the element

```js
cy.get('modal-top-element')
  .then($modal => $modal[0].remove)
```

If it appears in it's own iframe (seems doubtful), delete the iframe.