# Unable to interact with DOM elements due to ccc Overlay for Cypress Test running in Azure DevOps CI/CD pipeline

Tags: javascript, reactjs, azure-pipelines, cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

## How to Deal with Overlay issues in Cypress E2E Tests being executed in CI/CD Pipeline?

I have written Cypress (V9.7.1) E2E test that are being executed in AzureDevOps CI/CD pipeline.

I have noticed after recent upgrade of React App in FrontEnd, Same tests have started to fail in AzureDevOps pipeline.

Strangely Test runs perfectly fine locally but issues arises only when these tests are executed within CI/CD pipeline.

Is there a way I can disable overlay on the site through Cypress?

```
CypressError: Timed out retrying after 30050ms: `cy.click()` failed because this element:

`<input type="text" class="Input_textInput__7uTHu" placeholder="Search test" id="textInputSearchResults" aria-label="Search input" value="Power cut">`

is being covered by another element:

`<div id="ccc-overlay"></div>`

Fix this problem, or use {force: true} to disable error checking.
```

Thanks for the help in advance

I tried changing locators to Xpath by installing plugins but only achieved flaky results
Added/Removed waits

Comment: Can you refer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71527723/hiding-modals-popups-and-overlays-in-cypress) to check if it helps?