# Hide the entire HTML DOM except specific DOM

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to hide everything in the body except the table

I've tried

> body:not(#issuetable) { display:none; }

```
const css = `
    body:not(#issuetable) { display:none; }
    #issuetable th ,#issuetable td  { display:none; }
    #issuetable th:nth-child(3),#issuetable th:nth-child(5),
    #issuetable td:nth-child(3),#issuetable td:nth-child(5){ display:table-cell; }
`;
let style = document.createElement('style');
style.innerHTML = css;
document.head.appendChild(style);
```

The whole thing seems to be hidden. If you know please help.

---

```html
<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
      xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
    <head>
        <title>John's Done  (Apple Project Management)</title>
        <style type="text/css">
         table {
             mso-displayed-decimal-separator:"\.";
             mso-displayed-thousand-separator:"\,";
         }
         body
         {
             margin: 0px;
             font-size: 12px;
             font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
             color:black;
         }

        </style>
        <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=UTF-8">
        <!-- JRA-7598 - ensure fields (e.g. description) occupy only one cell - even fields containing newlines. -->
        <!--
             Vertical align all cells to the top, in order to align all issue rows of issuetable to the top,
             since Excel does not use or save the css files it is hardcoded here.
           -->
        <style>
         @page
         {
             mso-page-orientation:landscape;
             margin:.25in .25in .5in .25in;
             mso-header-margin:.5in;
             mso-footer-margin:.25in;
             mso-footer-data:"&R&P of &N";
             mso-horizontal-page-align:center;
             mso-vertical-page-align:center;
         }

         td.issuekey,
         td.issuetype,
         td.status {
             mso-style-parent: "";
             mso-number-format: \@;
             text-align: left;
         }
         br
         {
             mso-data-placement:same-cell;
         }

         td
         {
             vertical-align: top;
         }
        </style>

        <!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
            <x:ExcelWorkbook>
            <x:ExcelWorksheets>
            <x:ExcelWorksheet>
            <x:Name>general_report</x:Name>
            <x:WorksheetOptions>
            <x:Print>
            <x:ValidPrinterInfo/>
            </x:Print>
            </x:WorksheetOptions>
            </x:ExcelWorksheet>
            </x:ExcelWorksheets>
            </x:ExcelWorkbook>
            </xml><![endif]-->
    </head>
    <body>

        <table border="1">
            <tr bgcolor="#0747a6" height="30">
                <td colspan="11">
                    <img src="http://dev.apple.local:1234/images/jira-software.png" width="57" height="30" border="0" alt="John's Done  (Apple Project Management)">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="11">
                    <a href="http://dev.apple.local:1234/issues/?filter=11526">John's Done  (Apple Project Management)</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="11">
                    Displaying <strong>3</strong> issues at <strong>18/May/22 12:56 PM</strong>.
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        


                            <issuetable-web-component data-content="issues">
                <table id="issuetable"  border="1" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" width="100%">
                        <thead>
        <tr class="rowHeader">
            
                                                            <th class="colHeaderLink headerrow-issuetype" data-id="issuetype">
                            Issue Type
                                                    </th>
                                                
                                                            <th class="colHeaderLink headerrow-priority" data-id="priority">
                            Priority
                                                    </th>
                                                
                                                            <th class="colHeaderLink headerrow-issuekey" data-id="issuekey">
                            Key
                                                    </th>
                                                
                                                            <th class="colHeaderLink headerrow-status" data-id="status">
                            Status
                                                    </th>
                                                
                                                            <th class="colHeaderLink headerrow-summary" data-id="summary">
                            Summary
                                                    </th>
                                                
                                                            <th class="colHeaderLink headerrow-assignee" data-id="assignee">
                            Assignee
                                                    </th>
                                                
                                                            <th class="colHeaderLink headerrow-customfield_10100" data-id="customfield_10100">
                            Sprint
                                                    </th>
                                                
                                                            <th class="colHeaderLink headerrow-issuelinks" data-id="issuelinks">
                            Linked Issues
                                                    </th>
                                                
                                                            <th class="colHeaderLink headerrow-customfield_10101" data-id="customfield_10101">
                            Epic Link
                                                    </th>
                                                
                                                            <th class="colHeaderLink headerrow-updated" data-id="updated">
                            Updated
                                                    </th>
                                                
                                                            <th class="colHeaderLink headerrow-duedate" data-id="duedate">
                            Due Date
                                                    </th>
                                                                    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
                    

                <tr id="issuerow14995" rel="14995" data-issuekey="TI-325" class="issuerow">
                                            <td class="issuetype">    Bug
</td>
                                            <td class="priority">           High
    </td>
                                            <td class="issuekey">

    <a class="issue-link" data-issue-key="TI-325" href="http://dev.apple.local:1234/browse/TI-325">TI-325</a>
</td>
                                            <td class="status">
                <span class=" jira-issue-status-lozenge aui-lozenge jira-issue-status-lozenge-blue-gray jira-issue-status-lozenge-new aui-lozenge-subtle jira-issue-status-lozenge-max-width-medium" data-tooltip="&lt;span class=&quot;jira-issue-status-tooltip-title&quot;&gt;Awaiting QA&lt;/span&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;span class=&quot;jira-issue-status-tooltip-desc&quot;&gt;Awiting QA approval is defined as the QA manager has tested based on the feature requirements.  During this phase the reporter/business contact that requested this feature needs to also test and sign off on the feature.&lt;/span&gt;">Awaiting QA</span>    </td>
                                            <td class="summary"><p>
                Campaign - All Types - Values Not Being Passed on the UI (Export Factory XF Date)
    </p>
</td>
                                            <td class="assignee">            John Heng
    </td>
                                            <td class="customfield_10100"></td>
                                            <td class="issuelinks">                </td>
                                            <td class="customfield_10101">
            Bug Tracker - Go To Market May Release 2022
    </td>
                                            <td class="updated"> 18/May/22 12:34 AM </td>
                                            <td class="duedate">    &nbsp;
</td>
                    </tr>


                <tr id="issuerow14993" rel="14993" data-issuekey="TI-324" class="issuerow">
                                            <td class="issuetype">    Bug
</td>
                                            <td class="priority">           Medium
    </td>
                                            <td class="issuekey">

    <a class="issue-link" data-issue-key="TI-324" href="http://dev.apple.local:1234/browse/TI-324">TI-324</a>
</td>
                                            <td class="status">
                <span class=" jira-issue-status-lozenge aui-lozenge jira-issue-status-lozenge-blue-gray jira-issue-status-lozenge-new aui-lozenge-subtle jira-issue-status-lozenge-max-width-medium" data-tooltip="&lt;span class=&quot;jira-issue-status-tooltip-title&quot;&gt;Awaiting QA&lt;/span&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;span class=&quot;jira-issue-status-tooltip-desc&quot;&gt;Awiting QA approval is defined as the QA manager has tested based on the feature requirements.  During this phase the reporter/business contact that requested this feature needs to also test and sign off on the feature.&lt;/span&gt;">Awaiting QA</span>    </td>
                                            <td class="summary"><p>
                Campaign - Edit Page - Rules Parameters DO NOT DISPLAY CORRECTLY
    </p>
</td>
                                            <td class="assignee">            John Heng
    </td>
                                            <td class="customfield_10100"></td>
                                            <td class="issuelinks">                </td>
                                            <td class="customfield_10101">
            Bug Tracker - Go To Market May Release 2022
    </td>
                                            <td class="updated"> 18/May/22 12:36 AM </td>
                                            <td class="duedate">    &nbsp;
</td>
                    </tr>


                <tr id="issuerow14987" rel="14987" data-issuekey="TI-318" class="issuerow">
                                            <td class="issuetype">    Bug
</td>
                                            <td class="priority">           Medium
    </td>
                                            <td class="issuekey">

    <a class="issue-link" data-issue-key="TI-318" href="http://dev.apple.local:1234/browse/TI-318">TI-318</a>
</td>
                                            <td class="status">
                <span class=" jira-issue-status-lozenge aui-lozenge jira-issue-status-lozenge-blue-gray jira-issue-status-lozenge-new aui-lozenge-subtle jira-issue-status-lozenge-max-width-medium" data-tooltip="&lt;span class=&quot;jira-issue-status-tooltip-title&quot;&gt;Awaiting QA&lt;/span&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;span class=&quot;jira-issue-status-tooltip-desc&quot;&gt;Awiting QA approval is defined as the QA manager has tested based on the feature requirements.  During this phase the reporter/business contact that requested this feature needs to also test and sign off on the feature.&lt;/span&gt;">Awaiting QA</span>    </td>
                                            <td class="summary"><p>
                Rule Conditions have filled colored cells on Product and Marketing Campaign Detail
    </p>
</td>
                                            <td class="assignee">            John Heng
    </td>
                                            <td class="customfield_10100">CE Go To Market Sprint</td>
                                            <td class="issuelinks">                </td>
                                            <td class="customfield_10101">
            Bug Tracker - Go To Market May Release 2022
    </td>
                                            <td class="updated"> 18/May/22 12:53 PM </td>
                                            <td class="duedate">    20/May/22
</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
    </table>
    </issuetable-web-component>
    <div class="end-of-stable-message"></div>
            <table border="1" >
<tr>
    <td bgcolor="#f5f5f5" colspan="11"><font size="1">
        Generated at Wed May 18 12:56:37 UTC 2022 by John Heng using Jira 8.12.1#812002-sha1:7c28d59557fed9c1e3e470d7ce83e486c2b409b6.
    </font></td>
</tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What you're asking doesn't really make sense. `issueTable` is _a child_ of `body` and will get hidden. There's no way around that. Maybe give all your other elements a class and target that `.notIssueTable { display: none }`.

Comment: Oh … I see. I guess and I hide all tables and show only specific table then. That might work. Since there are 3 tables total.

Comment: this answer did not solved your trouble ?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72289968/parse-html-table-and-hide-columns/72290179#72290179

Comment: Yes u solved it

Answer (score 1):

Since the table you are trying to show is inside the body of the document, you can't use `display: none;` in the whole body tag.

Instead you have to use `display: none;` on all the body tag direct childs, except the one you are trying to display.

The only CSS you need for this is:

```
body > *:not(issuetable-web-component) {
    display: none;
}
```

If you have more than one `<issuetable-web-component>` tag in your document you will need to apply an id or class to it.

HTML:

```
<issuetable-web-component class="visible">
</issuetable-web-component>
```

CSS:

```
body > *:not(.visible) {
    display: none;
}
```

Now that you know what CSS you need to apply to your document, you can do it with Javascript using the following:

```
const css = `
body > *:not(.visible) {
    display: none;
}
`;

let style = document.createElement("style");
style.innerHTML = css;
document.head.appendChild(style);
```