# How to change a css value in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I want to change a css value in javascript, without having an element in html, I'll explain like:

```
<style>
.box{
width: 10%;
}
</style>
<script>
// I want to change the width value of (.box) to something like "90%" 
</script>
```

So what I mean to say is that I want to change the (.box) width value between the two style tags, I know my question sounds weird, but am just new coding and I really need it, any help appreciated!

Comment: This sounds like an "XY problem". You're trying to modify lines of CSS, that's not how CSS is typically used. Can you explain why you're trying to do this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's one option, adding a `<style>` tag dynamically. This will *add* a style which overrides previous, obviously. See other answers for other options of *changing* existing rules.

```js
var inline_style = `
  .box {
    width: 90%; 
    background: pink; 
  }`;

// from https://stackoverflow.com/a/28662118/3807365
document.head.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", '<style>' + inline_style + '</style>')
```

```css
.box {
  width: 10%;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">i'm a box</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Media_queries).

I don't remember the exact way to do this, but something like:

```
.box { width: 90%; }

@media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
    .box { width: 40%; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the properties (e.g. `width`) of a [`CSSStyleDeclaration`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration) with its [`setProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/setProperty) method.

You can get a [`CSSStyleSheet`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet) of a specific `<style>` element with its [`sheet`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLStyleElement#htmlstyleelement.sheet) property.

In our case, the stylesheet's first [`CSSStyleRule`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleRule) (`sheet.cssRules[0]`) is for the CSS class `.box`. You get the `CSSStyleDeclaration` object of a `CSSStyleRule` with its [`style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleRule#cssstylerule.style) property.

Example:

```js
const iClass = document.getElementById("i-class");
const classRule = document.getElementById("my-style").sheet.cssRules[0];

// Set input.value to initial width-value (10%)
iClass.value = classRule.style.getPropertyValue("width");

// Update width-value on each input
iClass.addEventListener("input", () => {
  classRule.style.setProperty("width", iClass.value);
});
```

```css
/* Ignore; presentational styling */
.box {
  margin-bottom: .5rem;
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
  background-color: coral;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<style id="my-style">
.box{
  width: 10%;
}
</style>

<div>
  <label for="i-class">Class width:</label> <input id="i-class">
</div>

<div class="box">class</div>
```

Unlike adding a new CSS rule, this changes the *existing* rule.