# Adding styles with js to the rss feed page doesn't work

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome-extension, rss

I am building a chrome extension. That extension appends an element to the body of the rss feed page.

I append a stylesheet to the head of the page. For the sake of the example let's say:

```
*{
   font-size: 54px;
}
```

It doesn't affect any element on the page but I just inspect the page and append this stylesheet to the head of the page It works.

Style that js appends

[image: before]

After I just manually append same style again, it works.

[image: after stylesheet]

Example rss feed that doesn't work: http://feeds.feedburner.com/experiment_podcast

what I've tried:

- delete all style tags and append it again
- delete all style tags and append it again but interval of 1 sec

I am not sure that is related to this problem but there is one thing I realized, when I append element into the body, its style property seems undefined. (my goal is append an element and change its style)

It works on any other webpages but not rss feed pages.

this is how I append the stylesheet

```
const style = document.createElement('style');
style.textContent = '* { font-size:54px; }';
setTimeout(() => {
  document.head.appendChild(style); // tried it async but no luck with that either
}, 10000);
```

---

It is not even related to chrome extension, when I try to append styles via console, it won't work either.

Comment: What browser do you use?

Comment: Edge @KonradLinkowski

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a <style> tag with Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/524696/how-to-create-a-style-tag-with-javascript)

Comment: No, I've created my stylesheet with innerHTML but tried it textContent, doesn't work either.

Comment: Neither of these is used in the accepted answer to the question I linked

Comment: Sorry, forget to mention that, It didn't work as well. I assume it is not related to browser and its version because it doesn't work only in a rss feed page

Comment: Use `document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml', 'style')`

Comment: Yes, that actually worked but it doesn't work with classes and since my element have multiple classes I need to find a solution for that one too :). But thank you I'll dig it up